# Set Terminal Title on Mac OSX

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying for days now, to set a custom Title to my terminal, I'm using bash as shell and I succeeded set a title only when a command is running with COMMAND_PROMPT. 
I would like to know if there is a possibility to make this title permanent and appear when I open my terminal window.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to set that permanently from **Terminal** > **Preferences** > **Profiles** > **Window**.

[image: Terminal Preferences]

Set your custom title on the **Title** textbox (ex. "TEST123").

You can also check/uncheck the other checkboxes here to show/hide the other elements of your title bar. For example, the "Active process name" will display `bash` (if bash is your login shell).

Try to uncheck them all then save that profile (**Shell** > **Use Settings as Default**) and restart your Terminal. When you open a new Terminal window, it should just show the title (and the current directory, which will get to in a moment) like this:

[image: PWD plus TITLE]

If you also want to get rid of the current directory, you'll have to add this to your `.profile` in your home directory (as mentioned on [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/21391/253138)):

`unset PROMPT_COMMAND`

When you again restart the Terminal, it should only have your custom title:

[image: TITLE ONLY]

Answer (score 1):

You can set the title like this :

> echo -n "\033]0;${USER}@${HOST}\007"

More info [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/Linux-mini/Xterm-Title.html#s3):

If you want this when you open the terminal, you can add your title to the .bachrc file

Comment: Thank you for your answer, well it's still working when I source my .bash_profile, but not when I open my terminal I put PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]0;${USER}@${HOSTNAME}: ${PWD}\007"' in my .bash_profile

Answer (score 1):

From the Terminal manual, if you look for "keyboard shortcuts" it states that you can edit a terminal title by doing:

```
Shift-Command-I
```